# Retrieve latest artifact from JFROG artifactory

Tags: versioning, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I have a few versions of my code in JFROG, which are provided to the clients. How do I specify a generic way to pull latest version(Artifact)? It is not Maven code. I looked up on the Jfrog page: 
'''
GET http://localhost:8081/artifactory/ivy-local/org/acme/[RELEASE]/acme-[RELEASE].jar
'''
How do I get [RELEASE] ?

Please help ?

Answer (score 1):

the `[RELEASE]` in this case is the version number you want to download the latest artifact for. To get that number you can use the REST API call for [Artifact Latest Version Search Based on Layout](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactLatestVersionSearchBasedonLayout). For example

```
GET /api/search/latestVersion?g=org.acme&a=artifact&repos=libs-snapshot-local
```

This would return a string of the latest release version you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the documentation at [jfrog](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SystemInfo)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Note that we don't enable the 'e' option, which would cause the script to
# immediately exit
set -uo pipefail

HOST=myartcloud.jfrog.io
USER=thisIsMyUser
PASS=thisismypass

SNAPSHOT_LAST_VERSION=$(curl --silent --show-error --fail \
                    -u$USER:"$PASS" \
                    -X POST  https://$HOST/artifactory/api/search/aql \
                    -H "content-type: text/plain" \
                    -d 'items.find({ "repo": {"$eq":"my-repo-snapshot"}, "name": {"$match" : "my-project-package-name*"}})'\
                    | grep -E -o -e 'my-project-package-name-[[:digit:]].[[:digit:]].[[:digit:]]+'| uniq | sort | tail -1 \
                    | grep -E -o -e '[[:digit:]].[[:digit:]].[[:digit:]]+')
```

Explanation. Making usage of `curl` with option

1. --fail (HTTP)  Fail  silently  (no  output at all) on server errors. This is mostly done to better enable scripts etc to better deal with failed attempts.
2. --silent Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages.  Makes Curl mute.
3. --show-error When used with -s it makes curl show an error message if it fails.
4. Then a post request `-X POST`  is made using basic authentication to the api path. The content type of the request is `-H "content-type: text/plain"`.
5. -d, --data  (HTTP)  Sends  the  specified  data  in  a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML.
   The data sent, is using a filter query to find an repository and also the content.
6. After the api results, using `grep` command line utility where it searches for PATTERNS and return only the version number.

Example: 0.1.1